# On div hover animate the hovered div from left to right off screen and animate new divs from left to right that were hidden off screen

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-transitions

How can I make using Jquery or CSS3 to animate a hovered div (on mouse over) to the left off screen and show up new divs one under other, here is a image link of the problem:
http://i48.tinypic.com/f12z6.jpg

Comment: Learn jquery, javascript, css, and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CSS 3 [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions):

```
/* out of view on hover */
.container:hover .hoverMe{
  margin-left: -200px;           
}

/* bring other DIVS inside view when mouse is over container */
.container:hover ~ .slidingOne{
  margin-left: 0;                
}

.hoverMe, .slidingOne{  
  transition: margin 1s;       
}

.slidingOne{
  margin-left: -200px;        
}
```

Assuming the markup looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hoverMe"> 
    ...
  </div>
</div>    

<div class="slidingOne">
  ...
</div>

<div class="slidingOne">
  ...
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DXTmc/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works great just i forgot to say I need to make the "slidingOne" divs linkable so they don't go away when i try to hover them but when i go off the area they go back to the start position and hoverMe shows again, is there a way to make that ?

Comment: I think you'll need to use javascript for that. I made a quick example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DXTmc/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS3's Transform property:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

What you're looking to do is "translate" the divs.  I would probably use jQuery to add the transformation class.